# How to call Laravel Accessor

Tags: laravel-4, accessor

in Product Model

```
public function getPaginatedAttribute()
{
    $posts = $this->posts;

    return \Paginator::make($posts, $posts->count(), 10);
}
```

when call in controller

```
$product = Product::with('categories')->paginated();
```

always error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::paginated();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an accessor here.

You can create a function in your model and then call it from your controller.

Product model :

```
public static function paginated()
{
    $posts = self::with('categories')->get();

    return \Paginator::make($posts, $posts->count(), 10);
}
```

Controller :

```
$product = Product::paginated();
```

Accessor are used to transform your model's attributes : 
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

I'm not sure this is what you want in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you're getting that error because you're trying to call an accessor from a builder.

```
$product = Product::with('categories')->get()->paginated();
```